# Accesing global variable giving linker error in objective C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, linker-errors, extern

I have declared a global variable like below

```
extern NSString *name;
@interface viewcontrollerOne{}
```

in implementation file i am accessing that global variable in some method like

```
-(void)someMethod
{
name = @"hello";
}
```

but this is giving linker error.

> "name", referenced from:
>         -[viewcontrollerOne someMethod] in viewcontrollerOne.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please visit following page
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026083/objective-c-linking-error-with-extern-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is merely a declaration:

```
extern NSString * const name; // << side note: this should typically be const
```

It declares there is a symbol of `NSString*` named `name`. It does not create storage.

To do that, you will need to provide a definition for `name`. To do this, add the following **to your .m** file:

```
NSString * const name = @"hello";
```

---

If you want to set it in an instance method, as seen in your example, then you can declare it:

MONFile.h

```
extern NSString * name;
```

Define it:

MONFile.m

```
NSString * name = 0;
```

then you can write `name = @"hello";` in your instance method.

Answer (score 0):

extern is tipically used to create contants. If you want to Create a global variable string, you can do it in the following way:

.h

```
+ (void)setName:(NSString*)name_in;

+ (NSString*)name;
```

.m

```
NSString* gName;

@implementation ...

+ (void)setName:(NSString*)name_in{
   gName = name_in;
}

+ (NSString*)name{
  return gName;
}
```